How to read Bluetooth Low Energy GAP characteristic values as a string?
Hello I am new to developing an app and even newer to the concept of BLE. I am developing an application on android using Java that is capable of scanning BLE devices nearby. The main purpose is to get device model / manufacturer and send it over to a server in a readable format. The app is able to discover them and connect on click. Once connected I'm able to read and view all the services UUID from said device. The UUID for GAP profiles is x180A which I understand is supposed to be the UUID for GAP. The device is capable of reading the characteristics which is highlighted as gray in the screenshot below. The question is the value that I am getting is in a hex string format. Is there any way to convert them into a readable string.
Below is a snippet of the code im using to display the characteristics of the service.
@Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = Objects.requireNonNull(characteristics_HashMapList.get(
                        services_ArrayList.get(groupPosition).getUuid().toString())).get(childPosition);

        if (Utils.hasWriteProperty(characteristic.getProperties()) != 0) {
            String uuid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();

            Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic dialog_btle_characteristic = new Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic();

            dialog_btle_characteristic.setTitle(uuid);
            dialog_btle_characteristic.setService(mBTLE_Service);
            dialog_btle_characteristic.setCharacteristic(characteristic);

            dialog_btle_characteristic.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic");
        } else if (Utils.hasReadProperty(characteristic.getProperties()) != 0) {
            if (mBTLE_Service != null) {
                mBTLE_Service.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
        } else if (Utils.hasNotifyProperty(characteristic.getProperties()) != 0) {
            if (mBTLE_Service != null) {
                mBTLE_Service.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

Here is the readcharacteristic method.
 public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

I have tried reading the hex value but have no idea how to transform it in a readable string format.

Many programs do hex to dec conversions - check the help.

The grey entries show two values in hex: the UUID and the read values.
Characteristics read values
There is no general format which allows you to interpret the values of all the different characteristic. For each official Bluetooth SIG standardized characteristic there is a specification you need to read an implement for parsing the read values.
Characteristics and services UUID
You need to maintain your own UUID to name lookup database.
If the service or characteristic UUID is an official one (has the format xxxxxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) you can get the 16bit respectively 32bit identifier from it. See How can I convert a Bluetooth 16 bit service UUID into a 128 bit UUID? for details.
Using this 16 or 32 bit identifier you can look it up in the official specification: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/
At the moment there is a PDF document where you can search for section Services by UUID and  Characteristics by UUID where you can find mapping tables from 16bit UUID to it's name.
If you want to generate a mapping database programmatically there is now also a BitBucket repo containing all the values in YAML format.
Some libraries contain BLE GATT lookup tables like RxAndroidBle: https://github.com/dariuszseweryn/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/utils/StandardUUIDsParser.java
But I don't know if these mapping tables are up-to-date. The Bluetooth SIG adds new standardized services and characteristics several times a year.

I believe the question was about converting the value returned by readCharacteristic, not the UUID of said characteristic

@MichaelKotzjan Possible but the then the only answer would be  read the specification of each characteristic how to interpret the values.

I totally agree!

@Robert Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

@AhmadDaniel Reading from and writing to a characteristic is like reading/writing to/from a TCP server (a server that does not use HTTP but a different protocol). For interpreting the values you have to know the protocol, therefore you have to read the protocol specification and implement it. Some characteristics have a very simple protocol like "Battery Level Status" which only returns a single value but some characteristics can return complex data structures or even needed to be accessed in a specific order (multiple read/write/notify characteristics).

@Robert Ok i think i got it. Let say im reading the device name characteristic part. How would i know or learn regarding the protocol? Is there a documentation you could provide with this?

@AhmadDaniel If it it belongs to a Bluetooth SIG standardized characteristic the protocol specification should be online on their web site: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

@Robert thank you so much. One last question. If the devices that i'm trying to detect is from mobile companies, like Samsungs Ultra 18 phones, which of these specifications would it be in? Sorry for all these newbie questions.

@AhmadDaniel If the service/characteristic uses the Bluetooth SIG UUID then it should follow the published protocol specification. If it is a custom UUID than it can be everything. Most of those custom characteristics are not published at all, therefore if you want to understand the values you have to reverse engineer the software sending the data or if there is an SDK/app for receiving the data then try to reverse this library/binary/app or whatever it is.
